# UITableViewController in UIViewController as a partial view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

I am new in ios dev, so my question might be so easy!
I want to use a UITableViewController in different places (reusable), so as a .net developer I think to create one UITableViewController and load it in different views (like Partial views in MVC.net) 
I know the UIView that wants to contain this table should implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods, but I don't want to do that, I mean I want the Partial view to handle all of those logics because that is the view that has the access to CoreData.

I already searched for different solutions and in almost all of them I have to implement those methods in every single view that wants to use that partial view.

any suggestion? 
Thanks

Comment: You will have to implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods for using tableview partially or fully. Rest is simple, just create a tableview programmatically and add it to your view with frame as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can handle the logic in the partial view for example your exTableviewController.
Handle protocol UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate in your exTableViewController as below.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Test"];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Test"];
        //                    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

And associate the partial view and your view controller as below.

```
@interface YourViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) exTableViewController *tableVC ;

@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableVC = [[exTableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:_tableVC.view];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@end
```

You can also customize the subview's size by using YourViewController.xib.
And binding self.tableVC with the subview in xib file.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks for the code, but it is not working, I mean the viewDidLoad of the partial view is not called.

Comment: Did you mean the SPTableViewController -(id)init is not called? I edit the code from SPTableViewController to exTableViewController to make it more easy to understand.

Comment: To avoid any misunderstanding, exTableViewController is the partial view in this example.